# search for multiple text strings in a div and remove html characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, find

So I have a badly formatted div with a bunch of inline CSS with `<p>, <font>`, and other old school tags. There are 2 text strings I need to grab and place those into a separate div higher up on the page.

Specifically, In the HTML below I need to grab the text after the word "CONDITION:"
But I don't want the HTML. The actual text is different on all pages but the HTML is the same.

```
<div class="content" id="content" style="display: block;">
    <p></p>
    <p align="center">
        <strong>
            <u>
                <font size="5" face="Arial Black" color="#990000">ONE NICE</font>
            </u>
        </strong>
    </p>
    <p align="center">
        <strong>
            <font size="5" face="Windings" color="#000040">MICHELIN</font>
        </strong>
    </p>
    <p align="center">
        <strong>
            <font size="5" color="#000040">ENERGY MXV4 S8</font>
        </strong>
    </p>
    <p align="center">
        <strong>
            <font size="5" face="Arial Black">215/55/17</font>
            <font size="5" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><br/>93V</font>
        </strong>
    </p>
    <p align="center">
        <font face="Arial Black">
            <strong>
                <font color="#990000"><u>CONDITION</u> :</font>
            </strong>
            <br/>
        </font>
        <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <strong>Approximate tread: 8-9/32<br>About 80-90% of tread life left</strong>
        </font>
    </p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Say "No" to [parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)! Here is another approach, simple and elegant:

```
var text = $('p[align]:last').text();
console.log(text.replace('CONDITION :', ''));
```

Shows: Approximate tread: 8-9/32About 80-90% of tread life 
left. See [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/95Xxp/1/)

**UPDATE:**

Since there are multiple content divs on the page, I've amended my code as follows:

```
var texts = [];
$('div.content').each(function() {
    texts.push($('p[align]:last font:last', this).text());
});
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95Xxp/4/).

Comment: I think this won't work since there is other HTML on the page. The div I posted is one of many content sections on the page. So locating the proper p[align]:last won't work. Any alternative suggestions? We do know this content always lives in the Content div.

Comment: @Mattman, have you checked the code? Is any of answers was useful? If yes, could you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick.

```
var found = $('.content').find('p').each(function(index, p){
    if($(this).text().indexOf('CONDITION') != -1){
        console.log($(this).find('font').last().text());
    }
});
```

Comment: If there are many p tags on this page is your method for locating this particular one the most efficient? If we know this p tag always lives in the Content div, perhaps you can locate it more efficiently with that container?

Comment: Oh for sure! I was merely showing you how I would find that section of text within this container... editing my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution http://jsfiddle.net/Yqsr3/

```
$(function () {
   var conditionElem = $('font');
    conditionElem = $.grep(conditionElem, function (e, i){
       return $(e).find('u').text() === "CONDITION"; 
    });
    var description = $(conditionElem).next().text();
    console.log(description);
});
```